# How to get the C file name from frama-c?

Tags: frama-c

I'm developing a plugin in frama-c using Cil_types.
This plugin takes as input the AST of a C program by default (Cil_types.file).
I want to get the name of this file but using Cil_types I couldn't.
Can I get this information otherwise?

Answer (score 2):

- `Kernel.Files.get()` will return the list of input files that have been given to Frama-C.
- `Globals.FileIndex.get_files ()` will return the list of files in which at least one global symbol of the current AST is declared/defined. In case you have some `#include` directives, it might be different from above.

Answer (score 1):

Moreover, you could also be interesting by the `location` field that exists in many AST elements. Its type is `Cil_types.location` and includes filename and line numbers.